# Ionic3, displaying images from sd (or any) storage on android

Tags: android, image, ionic3, storage

I am working on an app which takes images from an external api and then saves them to the device for offline use later on, which is essential. This is currently done via the **cordova-plugin-filetransfer**. They are stored in **cordova.file.externalRootDirectory** on my testing device now - I can see them and the files are okay.

Now I want to display these Images in a page, but however I do it - nothing works. So before ending things for today I thought I'd ask.

```
<img src="{{director.data_dir}}{{project.picture_path}}" /><br />
<p>{{director.data_dir}}{{project.picture_path}}</p>
<img [attr.src]="director.display_path(project.picture_path)" /><br />
<p>{{director.display_dir}}{{project.picture_path}}</p>
```

None of them work. I've tried several other ways, but I still get no image.
The director.display_path() strips the *file://* from the path as I've read I need to do this to get rid of this error:

```
Not allowed to load local resource: file:///storage/emulated/0/
```

Okay guys, what am I doing wrong? What should I do else?

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem, here it is how I solved. You need DomSanitizer and File:
Install ionic-native/file (https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/file/)

Assume you have 2 parameters:

mypath = "file:///emulated/0/Android/data/... .../yourfolder/"

myimage = "yourimage.jpg"

In page.html file declare  as:

```
<img [src]="cop">
```

Then in page.ts file:
- Import DomSanitizer and File

```
import {DomSanitizer} from '@angular/platform-browser'
import { File } from '@ionic-native/file';
```

- Inject them in constructor():

  constructor(private file: File, private sanitizer: DomSanitizer)
- Set value of cop:

```
getSanitizedImage(path, imageName){
      this.file.readAsDataURL(path, imageName)
      .then((data)=>{
        let sanitized = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(data);
        this.cop=sanitized;
      })
      .catch((err)=>{
        console.log("error: " + JSON.stringify(err));
      });
  }
```

Now, just call getSanitizedImage(mypath, myimage), your variable "pos" will be updated and the `<img>` object will display your image